# Expanding Formula to adjacent cells breaks VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, vlookup

So I had originally set up some VLOOKUP/MATCH formulas for about 1/6 of a calendar year. Everything worked fine. Well, when I finished adding the rest of the year, and chose to expand to adjacent cells, the VLOOKUP breaks and won't do anything past the original settings. I tried changing everything manually also and it just doesn't take. What am I missing?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10dkVIZYRDWPsCOjFU8zV7VgbVo3rFBkf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In the first part you join the 2 cells to form a string of [Month][Day], you then reference that to just a [Day], `MATCH` will return first match so you will only ever return January: =VLOOKUP(E3&E4,Data!A1:BM113,MATCH( **Dashboard!C4** ,Data!D2:BM2,0)+3,0)... I would also add that if you are dragging the formula you need to use absosule referencing ($A$1) the first $ locks the column (horizontal) the second locks the rows (vertical). Have a go and paste the formula you tried if you can't get it to work and I'll provide an answer tailored to what you have done.

Comment: So I added another row on Data! which just uses CONCATENATE to do the same thing as A:A. Then I wrote a match formula for both 1:1 MATCH(C3&C4,Data!1:1,0) and A:A MATCH(E3&E4,Data1!A:A,0). The items then use INDEX(Data!$A$1:$ABE$368,$G$3,$G$4) and INDEX(Data!$A$1:$ABE$368,$G$3,$G$4+1) since there are two items side by side.   Would this be better than a VLOOKUP?

Comment: INDEX is always better than VLOOKUP (waits for someone to prove me wrong) as it performs better and you can really reduce the size of the data that get's indexed as you don't need all the fields to be included. If you know how INDEX works, forget about VLOOKUP / HLOOKUP... I will take a look when I finish work, to say I'm busy would be an understatement xD

Comment: @RichardTompsett yeah index seems to be easier but idk